# What is "spilling the beans"? A proverb? A phrase? ...?

Tags: word-request

What is "spilling the beans"? A proverb? A phrase? ...?

For example, what to put in the blank below?

> Truth might be told mistakenly, **as indicated by ----- spilling the beans.**

Should I use "the phrase", "the proverb" , or ...?

And, is the second part of the sentence "as indicated by ... spilling the beans" idiomatic, or can be said in a better way? Aren't the followings better wordings?

> Truth might be told mistakenly, **what refereed to as spilling the beans.**
>
> Truth might be told mistakenly, **hence ..... spilling the beans.**

or other suggestions?

Comment: Spilling the beans isn't by definition accidental. It's *somebody's* secret, but not necessarily that of the person revealing it.  "I would prefer he didn't know, but Bob went and spilled the beans."

Comment: @StephenR Is there any other idiom that means when secret is by mistake or accidentally told?

Comment: “Let slip” comes to mind

Comment: @StephenR What about "letting the cat out of the bag"?

Comment: All such phrases are subjective, but I see that one as the same as “spilling the beans”.  You revealed something that *somebody* wanted to keep secret, but it’s not necessarily accidental on your part.  “Let slip” is similar to “slip of the tongue” — an unintentional utterance

Comment: Either one **can** be accidental, but aren’t necessarily so

Answer (score 23):

It's called an *idiom*. (You've used the term *idiomatic*, which means "having to do with an idiom." *Idiom* is the noun form.)

An idiom is an expression peculiar to a single language (although there may be similar ones in other languages) that has a unique meaning. We have another idiom with a similar meaning: *let the cat out of the bag.*

Your sentence would read like this, although I'll change it to better reflect what you're trying to say:

> Secrets can be accidentally revealed, as indicated by the idiom "spilling the beans."

What I might say is:

> "Spilling the beans" is an idiom that means revealing a secret that one was expected to keep.

(Spilling the beans isn't necessarily accidental.)

A friend's wife once invited me to his birthday party. I couldn't remember the time, so I called and left a message asking if they might call back and remind me. I got a call from his wife, telling me the time and that it was also to be a surprise party!! I'm glad my friend didn't hear the message, because if he had, I would have spilled the beans/let the cat out of the bag.

[Here's](https://blog.ted.com/40-idioms-that-cant-be-translated-literally/comment-page-9/) an amusing list of idioms from a number of countries, which will show the disparity of ways that different languages use idiomatic metaphors to convey common ideas.

The article mentions a Thai idiom *one afternoon in your next incarnation*, meaning "never going to happen." There is quite a list of idioms for this particular idea: two English ones are *when hell freezes over* and *when pigs fly.* Others mentioned in the article are *when hens have teeth* (French), *when a lobster whistles on top of a mountain* (Russian, and my favorite), and *when cows dance on the ice* (Dutch).

Comment: Quick note: I'm pretty sure "spilling the beans" isn't only _accidental_ revelations.

Comment: One thing both idioms have in common is the uncontrolled nature of the literal meaning. If you spill dried beans, they will skitter everywhere and getting all of them back in the container will be next to impossible. Getting a cat in a bag is a huge challenge, so once it's in there, you don't want to let it out until you're good and ready, because a cat that has been in a bag and then been let out will fight twice as hard to not be put back in. Much like a secret can't be retracted once it has been revealed.

Comment: What about the second part of the question? " ..., which is referred to as *spilling the beans*" or "..., referred to sometimes as *spilling the beans*", or ...?

Comment: I’ve seen cows dance on ice.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, actually, getting a cat in a bag is pretty easy.  Generally all you need is a cat and a bag, and the cat will do all the work.  Now, getting a cat that's been trapped in a bag *back inside* is significantly more difficult.

Comment: @RobertGrant Me too! I got caught up in fixing the OP's definition and forgot. I've updated the post, and thanks.

Comment: @user157323: i don't think either of your suggestions are better wordings. You have my "other suggestions."

Comment: @ToddWilcox Good observation!

Comment: @ToddWilcox I always thought that expression was when someone sold you a cat instead of a piglet ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_in_a_poke )

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Depends on the bag. I was thinking more of a burlap sack than a brown paper shopping bag, but your idea has a lot of merit. No matter what container you want the cat in, put out a brown paper shopping bag. Once the cat has inevitably entered that bag, then either place the shopping bag in the desired end container or dump the cat from the shopping bag into the desired container. I will remember this idea.

Comment: @RobertGrant Is there any other idiom that means the secret is by mistake or accidentally told? Only accidental revelation, I mean.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, "Spilling the beans" is referred to as an **Idiom**.

[Here's](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans) a link to an article linking the phrase to the term "Idiom".